# Can you install Compiz on elementary OS

Tags: themes, window-management, window-manager

is there any way to enable wobbly windows effect on elementary OS 0.4 I tried to install compiz but after i install it i discovered that compiz is not compatible with pantheon

Answer (score 1):

I answered this question here:

[Can you install Compiz on Elementary OS?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2591/can-you-install-compiz-on-elementary-os/14497#14497)

It is actually pretty easy to do! I got it to work with notifications, slingshot-launcher, wingpanel and everything else that seemed important at the time.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://entornosgnulinux.com/2015/05/16/compiz-en-elementary-os-freya/) are instructions for Freya, but worth a try in Loki.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "No".

It's technically possible to replace Gala with Compiz, probably, but you will break/lose notifications, the dynamic panel, wallpaper, many operations involving shortcuts, etc etc. You would have to replace each of these functions with something else to have a usable desktop again.